# CountDownTimer - how to start from another method rather than Oncreate method

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer

**Update**

I have figured the issue, actually I was calling the newCountTimer from another class and then stoping it from the class I made the function. I tried to call newCountTimer on Oncreate method of same class and it worked perfectly. I even tried to call this method from another method of same class, it crashed again. So, now my issue is how to start this method from another method as I only want to show timer after a particular task is done.

---

I have implemented a CountDownTimer, earlier I used Timer but that was causing more issue, so I changed it to CountDownTimer because of simplicity and when I try to stop the timer, the app crashes and restart the app. I am not able to figure out whats going wrong. Here's the code :-

```
public void newCountTimer(){
    countdowntimer = new CountDownTimer(21600000,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long time = 21600000 - millisUntilFinished;
            sec = (time/1000)%60;

            if (sec == 0){
                min++;
                if (min > 59){
                    min = 0;
                    hour++;
                }
            }
            if (sec < 10) {
                if (min < 10) {
                    if (hour < 10) {
                        timer_box.setText("0" + hour + ":0" + min + ":0" + sec);
                    } else {
                        timer_box.setText("" + hour + ":0" + min + ":0" + sec);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (hour < 10) {
                        timer_box.setText("0" + hour + ":" + min + ":0" + sec);
                    } else {
                        timer_box.setText("" + hour + ":" + min + ":0" + sec);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (min < 10) {
                    if (hour < 10) {
                        timer_box.setText("0" + hour + ":0" + min + ":" + sec);
                    } else {
                        timer_box.setText("" + hour + ":0" + min + ":" + sec);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (hour < 10) {
                        timer_box.setText("0" + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec);
                    } else {
                        timer_box.setText("" + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
           timer_box.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }.start();
}
```

I am calling this timer from my another AsyncTask Class, using this method :-

```
new Play().newCountTimer();
```

and I want to cancel the timer on another click of button using :-

```
countdowntimer.cancel;
```

Here's the Logcat I am getting :-

```
                                Process: com.ravibhardwaj.kbcmaster, PID: 17569
                                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22465)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6577)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647) 
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22465) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6577) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832) 
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.os.CountDownTimer.cancel()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at com.ravibhardwaj.kbcmaster.Play.lockOption(Play.java:547)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647) 
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22465) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6577) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

I am not able to solve this issue, please help in this regard. Their is nothing more related in anyway to timer in my app.

Comment: Do you sure newCountTimer() called before countdowntimer.cancel()?

Comment: yes, when new activity is created, newCountTimer is called

Comment: So how can it cause NullPointerException...

Comment: I figured the issue, actually I was starting countdowntimer from another class. and when i tried to run from the same class Oncreate method, then only it stops

Comment: Please see update, I still need to figure something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your `CountDownTimer` in `onCreate()` and start your `CountDownTimer` from wherever you want.

```
  CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000,1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        };
  }
  public void anotherFunction(){
      countDownTimer.start()
  }
```

Comment: still it is crashing

Comment: the issue is I want to start it from another class, my asynctask class

Answer (score 0):

Issue is solved I created the CountDownTimer as static and it worked fine.